# Questions about the definition of $\textbf{Comp}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

These definitions are from Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology. I just wanted to understand the definitions.
I need to give some definitions:

**Definition** A (chain) complex is a sequence of abelian groups and homomorphism
$$\dots {\rightarrow} S_{n+1}\stackrel{\delta_{n+1}}{\rightarrow} S_{n} \stackrel{\delta_{n}}{\rightarrow} S_{n-1} \rightarrow \dots  \ \ \ , n\in\mathbb Z$$ Such that $\delta_{n} \delta_{n+1}=0.$ Acomplex above denotes by $(S_{*}, \delta).$

**Definition**  If $(S_{*}, \delta)$ and $(S^{'}_{*}, \delta^{'})$ are complexes, a chain map $f\colon  (S^{'}_{*}, \delta^{'})\to (S_{*}, \delta)$ is a sequence of homomorphism $\{f_n\colon S^{'}_n\to S_n\}$ such that $\delta  _{n} f_{n}= f_{n-1}\delta^{'}_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z.$

**Definition**. All complexes and chain maps form a category, denoted by **Comp**,
when one defines the composition of chain maps coordinatewise: $\{g_n\}\circ\{f_n\}=\{g_n\circ f_n\}.$ Here are my questions :

> $(1)$ If $f,g\colon (S^{'}_{*}, \delta^{'})\to (S_{*}, \delta)$ chain maps. Then, $f_n,  g_n\colon S^{'}_n\to S_n$ . So, the composition $g_n\circ f_n$ is not defined.

> $(2)$ He mentioned that $\text{Hom}(S^{'}_{*},S_{*})$ is an ablian group.If :$f=\{f_n\}, g=\{g_n\}\in \text{Hom}(S^{'}_{*},S_{*})$ then $f+g$ is a chain map whose term of degree $n$ is $g_n+f_n.$ If this means  $(\text{Hom}(S^{'}_{*},S_{*}), +)$ is abelian or not. If so, the first two conditions are abviuous. Zero map is considered as a chain and $-f$ is the inverse and abian because $f+g=g+f$. Is that correct ? Thank you in advance

Comment: In a category, the composition operation is defined only for composable arrows, that is, for arrows f and g for which the codomain of f is the domain of g. That's true of the wannabe category Comp too: you need to take $f\colon (S,\delta)\rightarrow (S',\delta')$ and $g\colon (S',\delta')\rightarrow (S'',\delta'')$ if you want to make sense of $g\circ f$. Your resource didn't specify this because it implicitly assumed you knew about this general feature of composable arrows in a category.

Comment: For your first question, we should have $f : (S^1_\bullet, \delta^1) \to (S^2_\bullet, \delta^2)$ and $g : (S^2_\bullet, \delta^2) \to (S^3_\bullet, \delta^3)$. Then $g \circ f : (S^1_\bullet, \delta^1) \to (S^3_\bullet, \delta^3)$. As for your second question, if I understand you correctly, then you're right. $\text{Hom}(S_\bullet, S'_\bullet)$ is abelian basically because each $\text{Hom}(S_n, S'_n)$ is.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, Did you mean each $\text{Hom}(S_n,S^{'}_n)$ such that $S_n$ and $S^{'}_n$ are ablian. Right?

Comment: Yes, we assume the $S_n$ are abelian throughout

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, by $\{f_n\circ g_n\}$ means we will compose the corresponding $n$ terms in both chain maps $f$ and $g$. Right?

Comment: That's exactly right ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, I have some related questions to same the Category just wanted to make sure my understanding is correct since it is self-study.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, A sequence $S^{'}_{*}\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} S_{*} \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} S^{''}_{*}$ is exact in $\textbf{Comp}$ if and only if $S^{'}_{n}\stackrel{f_n}{\rightarrow} S_{n} \stackrel{g_n}{\rightarrow} S^{''}_{n}$ is exact in $\textbf{Ab}$. I think it is simple if the following is correct: $\text{ker} g=\text{im}f$ implies that $\text{ker} g_n=\text{im}f_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb Z$ IS that right?